# PHP Regex - Find url and text in html anchor tags

Tags: php, regex

Hi there I was wondering whether someone know how to remove both the url and the link text from all anchor tags in a big paragraph of text.  once remove if I could store them in an array for later use.

Im sure this is possible but I really struggle with regex.

Hopefully there is someone out there who has came across this before or who has some good knowledge on this.

Thank you

Comment: Can you show an example of what you're trying to accomplish?  What do you mean by "link text?"  The text inside of <a>tags</a>?

Comment: Other than the fact he said he wants to "remove" the URL and link text (he probably just wants to copy it), it seems like he's going to reconstruct the link somewhere else. Also, I'm not sure I can think of another way to interpret "link text" besides maybe, alt text, or title, but I doubt that's what he meant.

Answer (score 1):

Regex wasn't really designed to be a perfect html parser. Have you tried doing a simpleXML load string?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php

But for regex, check out these:

[What's the best way to remove <br> tags from the end of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135151/whats-the-best-way-to-remove-br-tags-from-the-end-of-a-string)

[How to convert multiple <br/> tag to a single <br/> tag in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133571/how-to-convert-multiple-br-tag-to-a-single-br-tag-in-php)

Comment: this seems like one of those things where using regex would usually be fine as long as the HTML was well formed (i.e. there's no link-within-a-link). If there's formatting tags inside the link you could just strip them out after you grab the link text.